# Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(String, int, int, LocationListener)'

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

```
Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(String, int, int, LocationListener)'
  try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,3,locationListener);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when wrote this code it give me error why it happen I am not understand when I use the the dot after `locationManager` there are 9 function overloading and I used `.requestLocationUpdates(String provider,minTimeMs,minDistanceM,locationListner );`

but still getting error please anyone help me.

`.requestLocationUpdates(String provider,minTimeMs,minDistanceM,locationListner );`

I am using right one still getting if iam wrong one use please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You have missed an argument in what you wrote. There is no method overloaded for requestLocationUpdates with just four arguments.
There is, however, this [one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.location.LocationListener)):

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, 
                long minTimeMs, 
                float minDistanceM, 
                Executor executor, 
                LocationListener listener)
```

which I think is the one you were trying to invoke. Notice there is an extra argument of Executor type.

There is an explanation about the Executor in the documentation:

> Executor: the executor handling listener callbacks This value cannot
> be null. Callback and listener events are dispatched through this
> Executor, providing an easy way to control which thread is used. To
> dispatch events through the main thread of your application, you can
> use Context.getMainExecutor(). Otherwise, provide an Executor that
> dispatches to an appropriate thread.

So in your case, you would need to add it to your call:

```
try {
     locationManager = (LocationManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
          LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
          3000L,
          3.0f,
          Context.getMainExecutor().
          locationListener);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: try {locationManager = (LocationManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);Context Context=requireActivity();if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,3,Context.getMainExecutor(),locationListener);}}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
still getting error brother  Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(String, int, int, Executor, LocationListener)'

Comment: @Abhisekpattnaik - You cannot send int values as the second and third arguments. You need to send long and float values. Notice the updated answer.

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        3000L,
                        3.0f,
                        Context.getMainExecutor(),
                        locationListener
                        ); Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, Executor, LocationListener)' bro getting same error after using the correct one

Comment: @Abhisekpattnaik - Bro, what methods do you see when you look at requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000L,3.0f,Context.getMainExecutor().locationListener); it give this error Non-static method 'getMainExecutor()' cannot be referenced from a static context .

Comment: and when i use HandlerThread or Looper instead of getMainExecutor() that time a get new error Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, Handler, LocationListener)' here the code       HandlerThread locationThread = new HandlerThread("LocationThread"); locationThread.start();Looper looper = locationThread.getLooper();Handler handler = new Handler(looper);locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
 3000L,
3.0f,
 handler,
 locationListener);

Comment: @Abhisekpattnaik- Bro, yo are not supposed to pass a handler, but an Executor object. Please edit your question to better reflect what you are trying to do,. In any case, it does seem like my answer helped you, so please mark it as such.

Comment: ok i understand that bro actual my problem is i need latitude and longitude so can give me the code previously given but i get error that  Non-static method 'getMainExecutor()' cannot be referenced from a static context that' why i am not properly understand because i am first time implemented